# ORA-02270 asignar una fk a una parte de la primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

Hola tengo problema ya que una foreign key está como una parte de la primary key de la otra tabla y por eso da el error, el modelo segun la solución del libro es tal cual como la planteo aquí, por eso no sé como hacer para que oracle lo asuma como bien.

El problema está solo en la tabla "Camino_peregrino", y es por la llave foranea que va a la tabla "recorrido"

```
    Create table CAMINO(
    nombre varchar (20),
    kilmetros_t integer,
    tiempo_t integer,

    constraint pk_camino primary key (nombre)
);

Create table CIUDAD(
    nombre varchar (20),
    comunidad_aut varchar (20),
    codigo_p integer,

    constraint pk_ciudad primary key (nombre)
);

Create table ETAPA(
    nombre_c varchar (20),
    numero varchar(20),
    kilometros_p integer,
    tiempo_p integer,
    ciudad_s varchar (20),
    ciudad_ll varchar (20),

    constraint pk_etapa primary key (nombre_c, numero),
    constraint fk_etapa foreign key (nombre_c) references CAMINO(nombre) on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_etapa1 foreign key (ciudad_s) references CIUDAD(nombre) on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_etapa2 foreign key (ciudad_ll) references CIUDAD(nombre) on delete cascade
);

Create table RECORRIDO(
    nombre_c varchar (20),
    numero varchar (20),
    ciudad varchar (20),

    constraint pk_recorrido primary key (nombre_c, numero, ciudad),
    constraint fk_recorrido foreign key (nombre_c, numero) references ETAPA(nombre_c, numero) on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_recorrido1 foreign key (ciudad) references CIUDAD(nombre) on delete cascade
);

Create table ALBERGUE(
    nombre_a varchar (20),
    capacidad integer,
    precio integer,
    ciudad varchar (20),

    constraint pk_albergue primary key (nombre_a),
    constraint fk_albergue foreign key (ciudad) references CIUDAD(nombre)  on delete cascade
);

Create table PEREGRINO(
    numero_I integer,
    nombre_completo varchar (20),
    direccion varchar (20),

    constraint pk_peregrino primary key (numero_I)
);



Create table CAMINO_PEREGRINO(
    numero_I integer,
    nombre_c varchar (20),
    fecha_paso date,

    constraint pk_camino_peregrino primary key (nombre_c, numero_I, fecha_paso),
    constraint fk_camino_peregrino foreign key (numero_I) references PEREGRINO(numero_I),
    constraint fk_camino_peregrino1 foreign key (nombre_c) references RECORRIDO(nombre_c)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> El problema está solo en la tabla "Camino_peregrino", y es por la llave foranea que va a la tabla "recorrido"

En efecto, para definir una llave foránea, debes apuntar a una llave primaria o única. `nombre_c` no llena esos requisitos en la tabla `PEREGRINO`, de modo que no puedes hacer eso.

Ahora bien, según entiendo el diseño de tus tablas (en el futuro, un poco más de explicación sería útil), la columna `nombre_c` de la tabla `CAMINO_PEREGRINO` representa el nombre de un camino, por lo que me parece más lógico que la llave foránea apunte a la tabla `CAMINO`.

La llave foránea siguiente sería lo correcto en mi opinión:

```
constraint fk_camino_peregrino1 foreign key (nombre_c) references CAMINO(nombre)
```

Comment: estaba mal la solución del libro, nombre_c corresponde a nombre de ciudad, un profesor lo aclaro, muchas gracias de todos modos por el aporte